# Vaadin, panels and overflow

Tags: java, vaadin, panel

I have a strange issue with Vaadin when trying to create a scrollable panel: I created a Panel with full height/width, and inside I put a HorizontalLayout with undefined width and height.

When I put items in the HorizontalLayout, and they are too much for the screen they just disappear out of the screen and no scrollbar is shown.

What is strange enough is that I inspected the layout with Chrome's DevTools, and found out that the HorizontalLayout takes a fixed width (that seems to be the screen's) even if I stated that the width is undefined. If I manually edit its width to a large enough value, the scrollbar correctly appears.

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code

```
public class Dashboard extends Panel() {
    public Dashboard() {
        HorizontalLayout hl = new HorizontalLayout();
        setSizeFull();
        setContent(hl);
        CssLayout component1 = new CssLayout();
        // Creation of the components of the various css layouts omitted for brevity
        hl.addComponents(component1, component2...); // Here I add my components
    }
}
```

This `Dashboard` object is then added to a `TabSheet` with full size: `tabSheet.addTab(new Dashboard(), "Dashboard");`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think the Panel needs a fixed width and height to be able to be scrollable. And because you've used setSizeFull(), the size is a percentage, not a pixel size. Take a look at https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.panel.html#layout.panel.scrolling

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the issue, I tried setting manually the dimensions of the panel but still the issue remains

Comment: A small update: for an error I got the component overflow both vertically and horizontally. The vertical scrollbar worked just fine, the horizontal still nothing.

Comment: "Normally, you wouldn't be able to put components with percentual size in a layout with undefined size." - [source](http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples-vaadin7/book/#layout.orderedlayout.sizing.undefineddefiningsize).  You use `HorizontalLayout` which has undefined width, and you put there `CssLayout` which has _"100% width by default"_ (https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.csslayout.html). So you break the rule: **A layout that contains components with percentual size must have a defined size!** (https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.orderedlayout.html#layout.orderedlayout.sizing.undefined)

Comment: Oh, I see. I missed the fact that the CSS layout had 100% width by default, in fact after a manual override of all the css layouts' widths (I calculated a "suggested width" based on the components inside them) and putting a layout.setWidth(...) everything worked just fine. If you'd like to add your comment as an answer I'll gladly mark it as the correct solution! Thanks! :)